# Will deleting a project in TFS remove the files, or will the history be preserved?

Tags: tfs

The reason I'm asking is that I want to test something, that I expect will generate a number of commits, totalling a lot of data, and since it's only a test, I don't want to leave them permanently in the database.

Do I have to set up a temporary TFS server for this, or can I just delete the project afterwards and expects its disk space to be reclaimed?

Comment: AFAIK, history _is_ preserved. Deleted branches are still there, only hidden by default (somewhere under Options -> Source Control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk space will not be reclaimed by normal deletion. You always have the option to undelete something in TFS, so changes will never get lost. (It's kind of a good feature in a source control system).

Do remember that TFS stores files as diffs between commits, so the disk space usage might not be so large as you expect.

You can, however, use [`tf.exe destroy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005.aspx) to permanently delete your changes. I think this will allow you to reclaim disk space (though I haven't tested  personally). Please be cautious if using `tf destroy`.

Comment: Personally, I would rather buy larger disks, than ever destroying something in source control :-)

Comment: We use the `destroy` pretty judiciously in our organization.  We try to reserve it for the big "oops" (as in an initial check-in in the wrong location).  Unfortunately, we sometimes have to use it to recover from the way that TFS treats deletes / re-adds with the same name.