# Will history be preserverd when doing a destroy in tfs?

Tags: tfs

Say I have two branches; master and child. I make some changes in child and merges them back to master. When doing a destroy on the child branch, will the history of the changes made in the child branch be lost or are they merged back into the master branch? Do I have to specify the `/keephistory` parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any branch or item that is "deleted" remains in history. Any branch or item that is destroyed is removed from the database and is therefore not in history. There is not a /keephistory option on a delete because all deletes keep history. I have not personnally used the /keephistory with the destroy command so I can't give you a recommendation on it. Just reading the documentation for it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005.aspx) I would guess that the difference between a regular delete and a destroy with /keephistory on is that the destroy can't be reversed.

In the situation you describe I would not recommend destrying the branch because that is where your history about who changed what lives. When you merge there is only a single check-in that includes all changes merged and it is associated with however checked in the merge.

Before TFS 2010 the history for merges was difficult to follow but possible if you took the time to figure it out. In TFS 2010 it is much easier to see the flow of a change through branches.

I could answer better if I knew your reasoning behind wanting to destroy but here are a couple things to think about: If you are destroying to help you reduce disk space 1) branches don't cost much because they only keep the difference not an entire copy 2)if you are destroying to save disk space and you use /keephistory I would guess that it doens't reduce the disk space usage. If you are destroying because OMG the code is trash and nobody should ever have the chance to be subjected to it's horror, then you are probably overthinking things.

Comment: What BitOff write is afaik almost correct. Branches can significantly increase disk usage if you modified content of the files a lot - even deltification will not help in this case. Destroying content of the files, while keeping the metadata, history of changes etc. is why /keephistory was added. If you just do straight destroy history of the branch will be lost.

Comment: Ok, but this is really one big disadvantage of TFS. When I merge something back I would like to merge the changes as well.

Answer (score 1):

I actually tested tf destroy /keephistory option in TFS 2013. /keephistory option actually keeps only the View History and Comments but deletes all the versions of the files. If you try to compare versions, you'll get an error that the file version is destroyed. So if you want to save the comments and the history of who changed the code but really don't care what the exact changes are, you can use /keephistory to save disk space. If you actually want to see and compare old versions, you should keep it in deleted status since destroy with /keephistory option doesn't keep the contents. If the code is useless or checked in with wrong name or something, do tf destroy without /keephistory to wipe out everything including View History and Comments.

Answer (score -1):

whether you delete the original source or not. Nothing in TFS is ever really deleted, simply placed into a "deleted state."

Check this link

[Will deleting a project in TFS remove the files, or will the history be preserved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880158/will-deleting-a-project-in-tfs-remove-the-files-or-will-the-history-be-preserve)

Comment: I think that is if you do a regular delete but if you do a destroy the file will be permanently deleted. From the link you posted: "You can, however, use tf.exe destroy to permanently delete your changes."

Comment: This is not correct as written.  "Deletes" will keep the actual content and revisions in history but they won't be seen in the latest version.  You can later undelete something if it was deleted.  However, "destroy" marks it to be removed from the database completely.  It isn't removed immediately but there is a TFS job that will find all of that and cleanup/remove content that was destroyed on a regular basis.